# header checksum error in wireshark

Tags: cisco, wireshark

[image]

hello all , I am not able to understand what kind of error is wireshark showing me please refer picture 
need help.

Comment: Less than 2 minutes with Google: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13577/header-checksum-error-incorrect-should-be

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In an IP packet header, there is a checksum value that is calculated to validate the integrity of the header. If this checksum value doesn't match, the packet is typically discarded. You can read more about [IPv4 header checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum) many places online including Wikipedia.

So what this error is indicating is that the IP packet header checksum isn't matching the IP packet headers. There was a day an age when this was always a bad thing, however technology is always moving forward. Today, many network cards can provide the ability to calculate and insert this checksum value in the headers itself (either specialized hardware or it's own CPU) so that the computer's CPU doesn't have to do it. This reduces the load on the main computer's CPU giving it more processing cycles to dedicate to other tasks.

Now when you are capturing traffic on a system, you are getting copies of the outgoing frames before the hit the network card (or after the network card has processed incoming frames). In cases where the computer is offloading the checksum calculation to the network card, it does nothing with this field leaving it blank (0x0000).

Wireshark does highlight these as potential problems, as normally a checksum mismatch is cause for the packet to be dropped. However it also does give the note `may be caused by "IP checksum offload"` indicating it may not actually be a problem.

Some people recommend disabling the checksum validation in Wireshark's preferences, however I personally disagree. If you do choose to turn it off, only do so while working on that particular capture and then turn it back off. Just because offloading is the most common cause of this behavior, doesn't make it the only one and if it is some other reason, you will want to see these highlighted so you can find out why.